# Overriding parent method in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

I have objects Sock and ChildSock which extends Sock.

```scala
class Sock
class ChildSock extends Sock
```

I also have a Human class, which can "wear" the Sock type, and a HumanChild class, which extends the Human class, and have a wear method, taking in a ChildSock, which should override the parent wear method.

```scala
class Human {
    def wear(s: Sock) = println("Sock worn")
}
class HumanChild extends Human {
    def wear(s: ChildSock) = println("Child sock worn")
}
```

Now, when I try run the following,

```scala
val csock : ChildSock = new ChildSock
val h1: Human = new HumanChild
val h2: HumanChild = new HumanChild

h1.wear(csock)
h2.wear(csock)
```

I get the following outputs:

```scala
> Sock Worn
> Child Sock Worn
```

But I want the messages both to be "Child Sock Worn", since the object csock is a child's sock. But I can **only modify the code for the HumanChild class**, and nothing else. How can I do this?

**What I've already tried:**

I've tried overriding the method in the class HumanChild like the following:

```scala
class HumanChild extends Human {
    def wear(s: ChildSock) = println("Child sock worn")
}
```

but it returned:

```
error: method accept overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class HumanChild contain the following, non final members named wear:
```

So I'm not too sure what to do.

Comment: This design fundamentally cannot work, because a HumanChild *is* a Human and therefore must meet the interface of Human. If you could override the wear method as you have tried to do then you could create a HumanChild and try to pass it a Sock (not a ChildSock), which must be allowed by the interface. However the method would expect a ChildSock which your Sock would not be. Hence the compiler cannot allow this override, although it can allow two different methods with the same name, as you observe.

Comment: There are a number of alternative designs you could use. Probably the easiest is for Human to accept a generic type parameter extending Sock, and HumanChild to extend Human[ChildSock]. I’m not at a computer but maybe someone else will write that up as an answer.

Comment: This question is an interesting topic that involves how the method lookup works. `Human` does not handle `ChildSock`, so when you pass a `ChildSock` to `Human`, it will trigger `wear(Sock)` and do a class hierarchy lookup to see which subclass overrides this method. Obvious no subclass overrides this method (your subclass only has a method that handles `Sock` but not `ChildSock`), so it resorts to the `Human::wear(Sock)` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `def wear(s: ChildSock)` does not handle the case where `s` is a `Sock` but not a `ChildSock`. So it cannot override `def wear(s: Sock)`.

You probably want something like this:

```
class HumanChild extends Human {
  override def wear(s: Sock) =
    s match {
      case _: ChildSock => println("Child sock worn")
      case _ => super.wear(s)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also introduce a type member

```
class Human {
  type S <: Sock
  def wear(s: S) = println("Sock worn")
}
class HumanChild extends Human {
  override type S = ChildSock
  override def wear(s: S) = println("Child sock worn")
}

val csock : ChildSock = new ChildSock
val h1: Human { type S = ChildSock } = new HumanChild
val h2: HumanChild = new HumanChild

h1.wear(csock) // Child sock worn
h2.wear(csock) // Child sock worn
```